# How to filter a table then the output to be printed in a pdf

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

Hi guys I am trying to filter a table then print the filtered table to a pdf.

I typed other codes but this is as close as i can get to finishing it.

I tried different solutions but cant seem to fix it.

If you guys have any suggestions on how to do it just say. Any help would be great.

Help guys! Thanks in advance!

This is reportss.php

```
<?php 
ob_start(); 
include ('filters.php');
  function fetch_data()  
  {  
  require('filters.php');
  $output = '';  
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "trans");  
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY created_at ASC";  
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {       
  $output .= '<tr>  
                      <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>  
                      <td>'.$row["first_name"].'</td>  
                      <td>'.$row["last_name"].'</td>  
                       <td>'.$row["email"].'</td>  
                      <td>'.$row["created_at"].'</td>  
                 </tr>  
                      ';  
  }  
  return $output;  
  }    if(isset($_POST["generate_pdf"]))  
 {  
  require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');  
  $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', 
  false);  
  $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);  
  $obj_pdf->SetTitle("Customer Transactions Report");  
  $obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
  $obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', 
  PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
  $obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', 
  PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
  $obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
  $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
  $obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '10', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);  
  $obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
  $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
  $obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);  
  $obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 11);  
  $obj_pdf->AddPage();  
  $content = '';  
  $content .= '  
  <h4 align="center">Customer Transactions Report for Viaje</h4><br /> 
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">  
       <tr>  
            <th width="26%">ID</th>  
            <th width="15%">First Name</th>  
            <th width="15%">Last Name</th>  
            <th width="33%">Email</th>  
            <th width="13%">Order Date</th>  
       </tr>  
  ';  
  $content .= fetch_data();  
  $content .= '</table>';  
  $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);  
  $obj_pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'I');  
  exit();

 }  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
  <head>  

       <script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">  
  </head>  
  <body>  
       <br /><br />  

       <div class="container" style="width:900px;">  
            <h2 align="center">Showings Customer Transactions</h2>  <br><br><br><BR><BR>

            <div class="col-md-3">  
                 <input type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date" class="form-control" placeholder="From Date" />  
            </div>  
            <div class="col-md-3">  
                 <input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_date" class="form-control" placeholder="To Date" />  
            </div>  
            <div class="col-md-5">  
                <form method="post">  
                  <input type="button" name="filter" id="filter" value="Filter" class="btn btn-info" />  

                  <input type="submit" name="generate_pdf" class="btn btn-success" value="Print" />  
                </form>
            </div>  
            <div style="clear:both"></div>                 
            <br />  
            <div id="order_table">  

                 <table class="table table-bordered">  
                      <tr>  
                           <th width="5%" >ID</th>  
                           <th width="30%" >First Name</th>  
                           <th width="43%" >Last Name</th>  
                           <th width="10%" >Email</th>  
                           <th width="12%" >Order Date</th>  
                      </tr>
                <?php  
                 echo fetch_data();  
                 ?>  



                 </table>  

            </div>  
       </div>  

  </body>  

  <script>  
  $(document).ready(function(){  
       $.datepicker.setDefaults({  
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'   
       });  
       $(function(){  
            $("#from_date").datepicker();  
            $("#to_date").datepicker();  
       });  
       $('#filter').click(function(){  
            var from_date = $('#from_date').val();  
            var to_date = $('#to_date').val();  
            if(from_date != '' && to_date != '')  
            {  
                 $.ajax({  
                      url:"filters.php",  
                      method:"POST",  
                      data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},  
                      success:function(data)  
                      {  
                           $( '#order_table').html(data);  
                      }  
                 });  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                 alert("Please Select Date");  
            }  
       });  
  });
```

This is filters.php

```
 <?php  

 if(isset($_POST["from_date"], $_POST["to_date"]))  
 {  
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "trans");  
  $output = '';  

  $query = "  
       SELECT * FROM customers  
       WHERE cast(created_at as date) BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."'  AND 
  '".$_POST["to_date"]."'  
  ";  

  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
  $output .= '  
       <table class="table table-bordered">  
            <tr>  
                 <th width="5%">ID</th>  
                 <th width="30%">First Name</th>  
                 <th width="43%">Last Name</th>  
                 <th width="10%">Email</th>  
                 <th width="12%">Order Date</th>  
            </tr>  
  ';  
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
  {  
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
       {  
            $output .= '  
                 <tr>  
                      <td>'. $row["id"] .'</td>  
                      <td>'. $row["first_name"] .'</td>  
                      <td>'. $row["last_name"] .'</td>  
                      <td>$ '. $row["email"] .'</td>  
                      <td>'. $row["created_at"] .'</td>  
                 </tr>  
            ';  
       }  
  }  
  else  
  {  
       $output .= '  
            <tr>  
                 <td colspan="5">No Order Found</td>  
            </tr>  
       ';  
  }  
  $output .= '</table>';  
  echo $output;  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: is `filterss.php` a typo in your question text? Because in your code you include `filters.php` and in that file you have a comment `//filter.php `

Comment: is the file called filters.php (as in the include) or filterss.php (as given in the text)?

Comment: @James sorry forgot to remove the comment and its just filters.php

Comment: @Mandyshaw sorry forgot to remove the comment and its just filters.php

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd also strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and much stronger guidance on how to write your code and organize your files. What you have here is quite a confusion of code.

Comment: `$query .= query();` doesn't make any sense. What is that supposed to be doing? It's calling a `query()` function that apparently doesn't exist.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: @tadman oh. okok. thanks bruh. noted

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: There's a lot of things to pay attention to in this code, so sorry for all the warnings and advisories but it's important to get those fundamentals under control.

Comment: @tadman im trying to call a function from a different php file. Am i even doing it right?

Comment: If you are calling a function defined in another file don't forget to `include` that file.

Comment: @tadman actually im just trying to create a code that filters (using date) a table and the output of that table be printed in a pdf . any advice?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "filter", which could be adding a `WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?` clause to your query, or it could be something else. There's a lot of steps between database and PDF.

Comment: @tadman yeah i am trying to filter date

Answer (score 2):

The `$_POST` variables you are trying to use will only be defined after you send the post itself.
The first time you load this page there is nothing in it, therefore, `query()` won't exist, therefore, you will see this error.

In this particular case, you should force the dates you want to use in your query in case nothing was sent from the form yet.

As of:

```
$fromDate = isset($_POST["from_date"]) ? $_POST["from_date"] : date('Y-m-d');
$untilDate = isset($_POST["to_date"]) ? $_POST["to_date"] : date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+5 days'));

if (isset($fromDate, $untilDate)) {...}
```

Though, as everybody pointed out, using global variables is not **RECOMMENDED**.

I also suggest you read this: https://www.phptherightway.com/
Helped me a lot a few years ago.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the advice. Ill keep that in mind. I changed my question  cause now i know calling a function wont work on my code.

Comment: If you are starting now with PHP, I would recommend the Slim Framework, since it's quite small but can really help you to understand some basic concepts of Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: Oh ok. Any advice on how to print pdf the output of the filtered date?